# Extraer direccion de rango con hoja y fila + columna

Tags: vba

Necesito extraer la dirección de un rango con nombre (llamémosle "mirango") de forma que me de la siguiente direccion en string:

HOJAX!$Y:$Z

Contraejemplos:
Si pongo [mirango].address me da $Y:$Z
Si pongo [mirango].address(, , , true) da [excel.xlsm]HOJAX!$Y:$Z

pero lo que necesito referenciar es el rango con la hoja y la fila/columna para un sistema que va cambiando la hoja de la referencia

Nuevamente gracias de antemano por su tiempo

Comment: Ni idea cuál será tu duda anterior. Las preguntas deben ser autocontenidas. Cuál es el contenido del rango (o un contenido de ejemplo)? Qué probaste? Qué falló? Por qué usas la etiqueta `vba` si no hay código VBA en tu pregunta? Recuerda que puedes [edit] todas las veces que necesites y añadir la info adicional

Answer (score 2):

Puedes suprimir el nombre del libro así:

```
Sub AddressDeRango()
    str1 = [mirango].Address(, , , True)
    pos = InStr(str1, "]") ' posición final del nombre del libro
    str1 = Mid$(str1, pos + 1) ' str1 = hoja y rango
    Debug.Print str1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
With [A1:B3]
    Debug.Print "'" & .Parent.Name & "'!" & .Address(True, True)
End With
```

El output que consigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El objeto `Parent` de un rango te devuelve la hoja donde esté ese rango alojado. Con eso sacas el nombre de la hoja. Y luego con la propiedad `Address(True,True)` sacas la referencia **absoluta** del rango (en mi ejemplo es `A1:B3` pero puedes poner el que quieras)

He englobado todo entre comillas simples porque en Excel, cuando se referencia a un rango alojado en otra hoja, si el nombre de esa hoja tiene espacios tiene que ir entrecomillado (comillas simples) o dará error. Si siempre lo entrecomillas, nunca te dará error sea el nombre con espacios o sin espacios.

De hecho, el output que tú quieres sería así:

```
With [Y:Z]
    Debug.Print "'" & .Parent.Name & "'!" & .Address(True, True)
End With
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]